# Implement amp multiple page slider

Tags: amp-html

Not sure if I use the term correctly, but on some amp pages there are dots in the header, and user can swipe left and right to go to previous/next page. An example here (notice dot dot dot thingy under cnn.com)

[image]

How to implement a slider like behaviour like that in AMP? I took a look at amp-next-page (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-next-page) and it just provides infinite scroll. So I wonder if we have amp built in for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The carousel here isn't something you can manipulate yourself. It's just a way to slide through articles that appear in the `Top Stories` area of Google search. This carousel is reserved for media organizations typically.

[image]

Comment: I am not talking about the search result page on google. It is the amp page when you tap on one of the those links in ur screenshot, there appears a slider on the header. So in your screenshot if you tap 'Met Police ...' news, then you will notice it. I also suspect that the slider is added by google, but there should be some way to tell google to group articles together right?

Comment: The carousels are the same, the in-article slider lets you slide between the ones in that top stories area. Google controls them, you can't link your own articles together like that.

Comment: yeah you are right they are the same carousel. Thanks for providing insights!